# I am unable to paste. Is there a solution to this bug that doesn't involve rooting or factory-resetting the phone?

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, samsung-galaxy-s-3, bugs

I recently updated my S3 to Jelly Bean (v4.1.1) and now cannot paste.

Example steps to reproduce my bug:
Compose message

1. Compose SMS
2. Type "hello" in body
3. Long press "hello"
4. Click copy icon
5. Click after "hello" to bring cursor / blue handle
6. Clicking "clipboard" does nothing (just dismisses handle)

If you're not having the bug, everything will work fine, I know. Please don't answer "it works for me". I know what should happen, but for some reason it doesn't work on mine.

Notes:

1. The bug is present everywhere you would input text (for example, in the gmail app, or pasting in an address bar etc.).
2. Pasting by using the options when long-pressing the cog in the keyboard doesn't work either.
3. Restarting the phone doesn't help.
4. The phone is not rooted.

Any other ideas?

Comment: I too face the same problem on my rooted Samsung Galaxy S I9000 running Android Jelly Bean 4.2.1

Answer (score 2):

I updated the software to 4.1.2 and the problem has gone :-)

I don't know if the bug has been fixed, or the process of upgrading has corrected the faulty state the phone was in. I'll update this post if the problem comes back...

Comment: Which update fixed the bug?